# Django Models XOR at the model level?

Tags: django, django-models

I am implementing approach #2 on this website.

Currently, I have:

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group,
                                 null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

**My requirement is that a Owner will have only a User or Group but not both.**

How can I enforce this when my scripts are creating them by directly calling `Owner.create`?

Comment: What is "approach #2"?

Answer (score 0):

Override model save to handle the case

```
class Owner(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  group = models.OneToOneField(Group,
                             null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.group != None and self.user != None:
       self.user = None
    elif self.group == None and self.user == None:
       <RETRUN ERROR>
    super(Owner, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```